# Как поставить выполнение цели Метрики на открытие VK Widget?

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, яндекс-метрика

```
<div id="vk_community_messages"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
VK.Widgets.CommunityMessages("vk_community_messages", 124094788, {widgetPosition: "left",tooltipButtonText: "Есть вопрос?"});
</script>
```

Как добавить выполнение цели Яндекс.Метрики при открытии виджета ВК? Через onclick для дива с id="vk_community_messages" не подходит, есть идеи?